# mkdir command not found with Python 3 on Debian

Tags: python, nginx, debian, uwsgi

I'm sure this is something simple, but I'm trying several settings and I just can't seem to get this to work.

I have the following code:

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen('mkdir -p /backups/my_folder', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
```

This is running in a `flask` application on `nginx` and `python 3`

When this executes I'm getting the following error:

> /bin/sh: 1: mkdir: not found

I've tried with `shell=False`, I've tried with `Popen(['mkdir', ...])`, and I've tried `subprocess.run` like this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)

If I run with shell=False, I get the following error:

> Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mkdir -p
>   /backups/my_folder': 'mkdir -p /backups/my_folder'

When I do `/bin/mkdir`, it works. But, there are other commands which call sub commands that fail (`tar` calling `gz` for instance)

What am I missing to get this to work?

Running:

Debian 9.8, Nginx 1.14.0, Python 3.6.8

**EDIT**

I need this to work for other commands as well. I know I can use `os.makedirs`, but I have several different commands I will be executing (rsync, ssh, tar, and more)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

I realized that my `/etc/systemd/system/site.service` uWSGI settings had a hard coded path:

> Environment = /usr/local/bin

Once, I changed this to include `/bin`, all my subprocess commands executed just fine.

Answer (score 2):

For these simple commands, try to use python instead of invoking the shell - it makes you more independent of the environment:

```
os.makedirs('/backups/my_folder', exist_ok=True)
```

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question to indicate that I need it on a general level. I have several commands I need to execute

Comment: I still think going python is the solution @CodeLikeBeaker - you can open tar and gzip files directly from python too. `subprocess` module will try to find the programs in the `PATH` and if they are not there, there is nothing python can do

Answer (score -1):

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen('mkdir -p my_folder', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True)
(result, error) = p.communicate()
print(result)
```

this is for only windows 10.

Comment: Sorry, but this does not work. It doesn't resolve the command not found issue.

Comment: I'm on Debian 9, not windows 10

Comment: PATH=$PATH:/bin         ------>this has solved your path problem.

Comment: Yes, because it wasn't set by default on debian, whereas It is on Ubuntu (at least 16.04)